# DataTable adding Columns to DataGrid instead of adding new rows?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid, datatable

I have a `DataGridView` that I'm trying to pull data to from an SQLite database.

The structure of the `DataGridView` is:

- `TaskName : String`
- `TaskDueDate : String`
- `Status : ComboBox`

**Code:**

```
String SelectQuery = "Select TaskName,TaskDue,Status from TASKS Order BY Status";
SQLiteConnection slite = new SQLiteConnection("data source = Dash.sqlite");
slite.Open();

SQLiteDataAdapter data = new SQLiteDataAdapter(SelectQuery, slite);
SQLiteCommandBuilder Command = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(data);

DataTable table = new DataTable();

data.Fill(table);
MyTasksGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
MyTasksGrid.DataSource = table;
```

I've spent the past few hours on here looking at several question including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114635/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagridview-in-c-sharp),
however it was producing the exact same results for me as the code above.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822123/bind-datatable-to-datagridview-that-already-have-column-defined-into-data-grid) question also suggests my code is correct from the accepted answer?

I get the correct amount of rows showing up in the grid, but all the cells are blank. If I remove the `AutoGeneratColumns` line it adds the data but in new columns, which I don't want. (I want it to be added in the already defined columns.)
Could anyone give me a hand to see where I am going wrong?

Comment: You need to add a binding which maps the column in the data grid to the corresponding column in the data table.

Comment: Thank You, that worked perfectly. Needed to set the DataPropertyName too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String SelectQuery = "Select ID,TaskName,TaskDue,Status from TASKS Order BY Status";
   SQLiteConnection slite = new SQLiteConnection("data source = SupportDash.sqlite");
   slite.Open();

   SQLiteDataAdapter data = new SQLiteDataAdapter(SelectQuery, slite);
   SQLiteCommandBuilder Command = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(data);
   var Bind = new BindingSource();
   DataTable table = new DataTable();

   Bind.DataSource = table;

   MyTasksGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
   MyTasksGrid.DataSource = table;

   MyTasksGrid.DataSource = Bind;
   MyTasksGrid.Refresh();

   data.Fill(table);
```

I also needed to add the 'DataPropertyName' in the control properties.